# MacTeX: Page-Up and Page-Down Keys Reversed in Skim and TeXshop

Tags: mactex

this may not even be a mactex question, because the problem occurs both in skim and texshop, osx Yosemite.  I like to look at documents in single page view, and use cursor and page-up/page down keys.  but they seem to be reversed.  page-up goes a page down, and vice-versa.  (chrome gets it right, however.)

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Yosemite. It's been discussed on the [Skim mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/skim-app-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04081.html) and various other places, as well. At least in the case of Skim, I don't see the problem when using "Single Page Continuous" mode (on the main menu, PDF -> PDF Display).